# (from LA done right)Prove that polynomials that always evaluate to $0$ at 2 is not linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Here is a solution. However from the solution I cannot see if the proof is complete. It seems that the proof only show that the list $z$, $p0$,$p1$,$...$,$pm$ are linearly dependent. But how can we see that the list is the linear dependent? In other words.  It seems that the assumption that the list is linearly independent is not used to get the contradiction.

http://linearalgebras.com/2A.html 
problem 17.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the website. Now I have added the website. @Alex Wertheim

Comment: It is assumed that $p_0, \dots , p_m$ are linearly independent and a contradiction is reached. So they must be linearly dependent. The assumption is used here to apply problem 11.

Comment: Sorry I so far I cannot get it clear yet... Could you please explain how it use the question 11? What I can see yet is only if we assume the list is linearly dependent then by problem 11 we can get a1,a2,a3.....not all zero such that...@Crostul

Comment: I think whether p1,p2....pm are linearly independent or dependent, the list of length m+2 is always linearly dependent.i.e. z, p0,p1....pm are always linearly dependent.

Comment: Problem 11 uses some linearly independent vectors (in this case $p_1, \dots , p_m$) and another vector (in this case $z$). Now, $z, p_1, \dots , p_m$ are linearly dependent, hence by problem 11 you have $z \in \mathrm{span} (p_1, \dots ,p_m)$. After that, you have a contradiction. So we have that the initial assumption ($p_1, \dots ,p_m$ linearly independent) is false: hence they must be linearly dependent.